# Insert Command Dont insert into database?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

HI

could someone tell me what i am doing wrong in this code

```
Protected Sub insert_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Insert.Click
    Dim mydb As New OleDbConnection
    mydb = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= |datadirectory|database.mdb;Persist Security Info=True")
    mydb.Open()
    Dim sqlstring = "INSERT INTO [maintable] ([field1], [field2]) VALUES (@textbox1, @textbox2);"
    Dim mydbcommand As New OleDbCommand(sqlstring, mydb)
    TextBox1.Text = mydbcommand.Parameters.Add("@textbox1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value
    TextBox2.Text = mydbcommand.Parameters.Add("@textbox2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value 
    mydbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    mydb.Close()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you should use

```
mydbcommand.Parameters.Add("@textbox1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
mydbcommand.Parameters.Add("@textbox2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
```

instead of

```
 TextBox1.Text = mydbcommand.Parameters.Add("@textbox1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value
 TextBox2.Text = mydbcommand.Parameters.Add("@textbox2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value
```

try it and tell me if you still face the problem